# How to link two LLVM bitcode modules?

Tags: c++, linker, llvm, compiler-optimization, static-linking

I have a simple LLVM pass that renames every function defined within the current translation unit (i.e: the source file in question, after all preprocessing steps have taken place - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146425/llvm-translation-unit)). My pass is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallString.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/TypeFinder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Argument.h"
#include "llvm/IR/GlobalValue.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {

  struct FunctionRename : public ModulePass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification
    FunctionRename() : ModulePass(ID) {}

    bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {
      // Rename all functions
      for (auto &F : M) {
        StringRef Name = F.getName();
        // Leave library functions alone because their presence or absence
        // could affect the behaviour of other passes.
        if (F.isDeclaration())
          continue;
        F.setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkOnceAnyLinkage);
        F.setName(Name + "_renamed");
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
}

char FunctionRename::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<FunctionRename> X("functionrename", "Function Rename Pass");
// ===-------------------------------------------------------==//
//
// Function Renamer - Renames all functions
//
```

After running the pass over a bitcode file, `file.bc`, I output the result to a new file `file_renamed.bc`, as follows

`opt -load /path/to/libFunctionRenamePass.so -functionrename < file.bc > file_renamed.bc`

I then attempt to link the two files as follows

`llvm-link file.bc file_renamed.bc -o file_linked.bc`

However, I still get symbol clashes for C++ source files (from which the initial bitcode file is generated) where constructors and destructors are involved. My expectation was that the line

`F.setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkOnceAnyLinkage)`

would prevent symbol clashes occurring for any symbols defined in `file.bc` and `file_renamed.bc`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the actual text of the errors you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My full solution is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallString.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/TypeFinder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Argument.h"
#include "llvm/IR/GlobalValue.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Metadata.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {

  struct FunctionRename : public ModulePass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification
    FunctionRename() : ModulePass(ID) {}

    bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {

      for (auto it = M.global_begin(); it != M.global_end(); ++it)
      {
        GlobalVariable& gv = *it;
        if (!gv.isDeclaration())
          gv.setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkerPrivateLinkage);
      }

      for (auto it = M.alias_begin(); it != M.alias_end(); ++it)
      {
        GlobalAlias& ga = *it;
        if (!ga.isDeclaration())
          ga.setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkerPrivateLinkage);
      }

      // Rename all functions
      for (auto &F : M) {
        StringRef Name = F.getName();
        // Leave library functions alone because their presence or absence
        // could affect the behaviour of other passes.
        if (F.isDeclaration())
          continue;
        F.setLinkage(GlobalValue::WeakAnyLinkage);
        F.setName(Name + "_renamed");
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
}

char FunctionRename::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<FunctionRename> X("functionrename", "Function Rename Pass");
// ===-------------------------------------------------------==//
//
// Function Renamer - Renames all functions
//
```

In the loop to process the functions, `for(auto &F : M) { ... }`, I prefer to use `WeakAnyLinkage` instead of `LinkOnceAnyLinkage` for the following reasons.

Globals with `LinkOnceAnyLinkage` - as the name suggests - are merged with other symbols of the same name when linkage occurs, and unreferenced globals with this linkage are allowed to be discarded.

Globals with `WeakAnyLinkage` share the same semantics of globals with `LinkOnceAnyLinkage`, except that unreferenced globals with `WeakAnyLinkage` may not be discarded.

Also, in the two loops to process globals and aliases, I use `LinkerPrivateLinkage`, because I do not want the globals in `file_renamed.bc` to be accessible by any objects outside this module.

Also, the loop for processing aliases is necessary (at least on my environment) for avoiding symbol clashes related to complete-object constructors and destructors (i.e: C1 and D1 destructors as per Itanium C++ ABI).

Answer (score 1):

When I tried running your code on a sample bitcode file, the llvm-link step failed due to the global variables:

```
ERROR: Linking globals named 'my_global': symbol multiply defined!
```

After adding a second loop to the RunOnModule routine to process the global variables, llvm-link succeeds and then the code ultimately linked.

```
for (auto git = M.global_begin(), get = M.global_end(); git != get; ++git)
{
   GlobalValue* gv = &*git;
   gv->setLinkage(GlobalValue::LinkOnceAnyLinkage);
}
```

However, my simple test of C++ code with constructors worked both with and without this change.