# Does a tool exist to process preprocessor directives and give the actual preprocessor output?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preprocessor output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742822/preprocessor-output)

I have found myself debugging STL Port for Android.  It uses many (10-100?) preprocessor directives throughout to decide what code is actually output by the preprocessor.  Lots of `#if` and `#ifdef` blocks.

Is there a tool available that can run through these and show what text is actually sent to the compiler?  Is it possible to see the output of the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2):

In GCC, use `gcc -E source.c` to show the output of the preprocessor only.

Same for Clang I believe.

For other compilers, see the manual. This should be clearly documented.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed this!  Thanks.  One quick question: when reading the output, is it true that only the lines not starting with '#' are send to the compiler?

Comment: @AdamS: Not really. The remaining directives are still needed by the compiler to produce the correct file name and line number output in error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Wave](http://www.boost.org/libs/wave/) was created for.

> The Wave C++ preprocessor library is a Standards conformant implementation of the mandated C99/C++ preprocessor functionality packed behind a simple to use interface, which integrates well with the well known idioms of the Standard Template Library (STL).

Answer (score 0):

Almost any C++ compiler I used has its command line switch to perform this task; on g++ it's `-E` (which writes the output on `stdout`, see the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)), on VC++ it's [`/EP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/becb7sys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (output to `stdout`) or [`/P`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (output to file).

Comment: For VC++, there's also `/E` and `/EP`.