# Where do we use .i files and how do we generate them?

Tags: c, gcc, file-extension

I was going through the GCC man page, I found the following line:

```
 file.i
           C source code that should not be preprocessed.
```

I know that running `gcc -E foo.c` stops the compiler after preprocessing;
but what is the real world application of creating `.i` files.

Also is there a way of generating a `.i` files other than `gcc foo.c -E > foo.i`?

Comment: Another way is `gcc --save-temps -o foo foo.c`

Comment: One real-world use is in reporting compiler bugs. You send the `.i` file that triggers the bug, so it can be reproduced by someone who doesn't have your headers. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#need

Comment: See also: [How to view C preprocessor output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742822/4561887). I'm especially a fan of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127046/4561887).

Answer (score 23):

The `.i` files are also called as "Pure C files". In preprocessing stage

1. Header files will be included.
2. Macros will be replaced.
3. Comments are removed.
4. Used for conditional compilation.
   If you look at the `.i` file you can see these things.

Command to generate `.i` file is-

```
gcc -E foo.c -o foo.i
```

Answer (score 13):

### A `.i` file is an "intermediate" preprocessed file, or "single translation unit"

"Intermediate" means in this case: "between the stages of preprocessing and compiling", where the build process includes:

1. Preprocessing
2. Compiling
3. Assembling
4. Linking

Therefore, per `man gcc`, a `file.i` file is:

> C source code that should not be preprocessed.

*Source*: `man gcc` then press the <kbd>/</kbd> key to search, and search for "`\.i`".
*Detailed Steps*: `man gcc`, then press the <kbd>/</kbd> key to search, then type in `\.i`, then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then press the <kbd>n</kbd> key repeatedly until you find it.

What this means is that a `.i` file is **preprocessed source code**, so it *has already been preprocessed*. Therefeore, it already contains:

1. all header files included
2. macros replaced
3. and comments removed

...as [stated by @Sathish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25137914/4561887) in his answer.

You'll also notice a ton of special "comments" added by gcc that now begin with the `#` character, such as these:

> ```
> # 1 "main.c"  
> # 1 "<built-in>"  
> # 1 "<command-line>"  
> # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4  
> # 1 "<command-line>" 2  
> # 1 "main.c"  
> # 44 "main.c"  
> # 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4  
> # 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4  
> # 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4  
> # 374 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4  
> # 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
> ```

I don't know what those are nor what they do. Someone please tell me if you know.

Note that a simple program such as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -O0 -save-temps=obj main.c -o ./bin/main
```

Will produce a `main.i` file that is about 682 lines long, with the `main()` function shown above being right at the very end.

### How to generate all intermediate files, including the `.i` files:

My preference is to generate *all* intermediate files (`.i`, `.o`, `.s`, rather than just the `.i` file using `-E`) all at once in a local `bin` folder in the project by using the `gcc` `-save-temps=obj` option like this:

```
mkdir bin
gcc -save-temps=obj foo.c -o ./bin/foo
```

Now you have the following files in the "foo/bin" directory:

> ```bash
> foo     # compiled binary program (AKA: combined "object file", 
>         # "executable", "binary", "program", or "machine code")
> foo.i   # intermediate, preprocessed C file  
> foo.o   # individual object file  
> foo.s   # assembly file
> ```

Run the program of course with:

```
./bin/foo
```

### Notes about "object files" and "executables"

Note that the final output, the `foo` executable file, is called the "**compiled binary program**", "**program**", **(combined) "object file**", "**executable**", "**binary**", or just "**machine code**", or "**ones and zeros**" (10101010). It is an *object file* in *object file format*, as are the individual `*.o` *object files* which are combined into one by the *linker* to create it. The linker combines all `*.o` object files into one in order to make the final `foo` executable, or combined *object file*.

The GNU linker (`ld`) manual states it as follows. See section "3.1 Basic Linker Script Concepts": https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts (emphasis added, as well as content in square brackets `[]`):

> **3.1 Basic Linker Script Concepts**
>
> We need to define some basic concepts and vocabulary in order to describe the linker script language.
>
> The linker combines input files [individual `*.o` object files] into a **single output file.** The output file and each input file are in a special data format known as an *object file format*. Each file is called an *object file*. The output file is often called an *executable*, but for our purposes we will also call it an object file. Each object file has, among other things, a list of *sections*. We sometimes refer to a section in an input file as an *input section*; similarly, a section in the output file is an *output section*.

For more info. on object files, you can also see two of my other answers here:

1. [How do I find out at compile time how much of an STM32's Flash memory and dynamic memory (SRAM) is used up?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/363931/how-do-i-find-out-at-compile-time-how-much-of-an-stm32s-flash-memory-and-dynami/523439#523439)
2. [Convert binutils `size` output from "sysv" format (`size --format=sysv my_executable`) to "berkeley" format (`size --format=berkeley my_executable`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073080/convert-binutils-size-output-from-sysv-format-size-format-sysv-my-execut/64080798#64080798)

### See also

1. This answer by @Ciro Santilli OurBigBook.com: [How to view C preprocessor output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127046/4561887)