# Generate preprocesed file ( .i ) in code blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am following  [The Cherno C++ series](https://youtu.be/H4s55GgAg0I) and in this video  he is talking about generating .i files. I am an Ubuntu [20.04] user and am making my projects on Code::Blocks. Does any one know how to generate .i files in Code::Blocks?

Comment: You can do it with a command line shell. [Where do we use .i files and how do we generate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137743/where-do-we-use-i-files-and-how-do-we-generate-them) To do it in an IDE you would need to change the compile command or add a new one. You'd want to refer to the documentation for how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you can't directly genrate a preprocessor file in Code::Blocks
as far as my knowledge go. Because I am also following the same series and I also had this problem { i am also using C::b }, so what you can do is in ubuntu terminal go to that file location by using `cd` command and then use

```
g++ -E FileName.c -o FileName.i
```

command this will genrate the preprocessor file.