# Accessing a variable declared in an outer 'for' loop is faster than one defined in an inner 'for' loop in C

Tags: c, time

I happened to find out that this code:

```c
int main() {
    int result = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            result += i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is faster than the following:

```c
int main() {
    int result = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            result += j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where the only change is whether the result is updated by `i` or `j`.

Specifically on my system, the first code takes ~18.1 seconds and the second code takes ~19.9 seconds (measured using the `time` command on Linux).

However, if I measure the following code:

```c
int main() {
    int result = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        int i2 = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            int j2 = 1;
            result += i2;  // Or j2
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it does **not** matter whether I access `i2` or `j2`! They both take ~17.8 seconds.

I do not understand where this time difference between accessing `i` and `j` comes from **exactly**, and why it does not appear in the last example. What is the explanation in **low-level** terms?

I was not aware of optimizations, and I compiled the program with `gcc main.c`

After fixing the overflow error as pointed by the comments, even without optimizations, the time difference is almost insignificant!

The overflow error was solved by replacing `result += i;` to `result += i - i;` (same for `j`).

Comment: I think you should study the assembly. Look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482777/4561887) for how to get it. In short, add `-save-temps=obj` to your gcc build command, and then you'll get a `.s` assembly file. Also, turn on full optimizations with `-O3` and then compare the output.

Comment: You're most likely testing an unoptimized build (since if it was optimized then the whole loop would be optimized away). Benchmarking unoptimized code is usually pointless and the results would heavily depend on the compiler.

Comment: How do you build your program? Any kind of benchmarking is more or less useless on unoptimized code. Enable optimizations when building.

Comment: Also worth noting is that your code will lead to overflow of the `result` variable. And overflow of signed integers leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @interjay Indeed. I was not using optimizations as I was not aware. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated the question to show I was building the program with `gcc main.c`. I was not aware of optimizations. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The end value of `result` is different in the first two programs, assuming you remove the undefined behaviour by changing the loop limit or by using an unsigned type for `result`. Overflowing a signed integer is undefined behaviour — anything is possible.  And if the result is different, then it is not unreasonable for the time taken to produce that result to be different.

Comment: Until you test with `-O3` any conclusions you have are irrelevant. Keep in mind your code reduces to "do nothing and exit" so don't be surprised if that happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not comparing the first 2 codes with the last one. I am comparing the first 2 codes by themselves.

Comment: Yes.  I should correct/clarify my statement.  At the end of any given intermediate iteration of the outer loop, the value in `result` is different in version 1 from the value in version 2.  The computations are different, even though the final result is the same.  I changed `result` to `unsigned long` (on a 64-bit machine: no UB), created two functions, one for each version of the code, and modified them to return the result (and to print some intermediate values of `result`).  The final result is the same — `499995000000000`, but after the first loop, `result` contains `0` or `4999950000`.