# what is the output of this according to the macro definition

Tags: c, macros

```
#define A 1+2
#define B 4+3

int main()
{
   int val = A*B;
   printf("%d",val);
}
```

Here A and B is defined, and val is (A*B). What is the correct output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742822/preprocessor-output

Comment: It is trivial to find out by performing the substitution yourself: `A*B` --> `1+2*4+3`, and applying primary school math skills.

Comment: How do you determine the correctness of the output? (1) It is what you think it should do, or (2) it is what the compiler tells you it is? Do they differ?

Comment: `12` (you forgot to state what you **think** is correct). Just tell me where to pick up the car I won.

Answer (score 3):

Let's trace the expansion and calculation manually.

`A*B` -> `1+2*4+3` -> `1+8+3` -> `12`

As a result, the output will be `12`

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with Macros. When you define something even as x+y in a macro it is advisable to first rap them in `()` so as to "protect" the operation.
As such it would be better to define `A` as `(1+2)` etc. Otherwise you get the output `1+2*4+3=12` as people have stated above.