# C++ - Why am i getting Linkage errors? C Linkage Error - Bazel Build

Tags: c++, c, bazel, linkage

I'm trying to build a project using bazel and a C++ STLport library. When I build the program, I get multiple errors such as:

`libs/std/type_traits:286:1: error: template with C linkage
  template <class _Tp>
  ^`

I've looked at other questions that all mention i need to remove the include from an extern "C" {} but there are no extern "C" statements in the code. Any idea?

Comment: You might have an unclosed `extern "C" {` prior to this

Comment: There are no `extern "C" {}` statements in my code, unfortunately.

Comment: What's just before `type_traits:286:1`  previous few lines please (line 286 is a funny place to start going wrong in a standard header file).  Also check for macro expansions from the build system being substituted in unexpected places.

Comment: Can you make your compiler output the preprocessed code? You might find more clues there. E.g. g++ -E . https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742831/451600

Comment: `__CV_SPEC(is_floating_point,float,true);
__CV_SPEC(is_floating_point,double,true);
__CV_SPEC(is_floating_point,long double,true);

template <class _Tp>
struct is_array :
    public false_type
{ };
` The code falls over multiple times before before that with the same errors but this is what is specifically before this error.

Comment: The 1st error is the important one and the few lines before are probably the cause.

Comment: `template <class _Tp, _Tp __v>
struct integral_constant
{
    static const _Tp                    value = __v;
    // enum { value = __v }; ?

    typedef _Tp                         value_type;
    typedef integral_constant<_Tp, __v> type;
};`

The error that comes with this is:

`In file included from libs/std/utility:28:0,
                 from libs/std/stl/_algobase.h:51,
                 from libs/std/algorithm:39,
                 from libs/span.h:6:
libs/std/type_traits:38:1: error: template with C linkage
 template <class _Tp, _Tp __v>
 ^
`