# Paste token at beginning of C/C++ macro definition

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there anyway to token paste a parameter or non-function macro at the BEGINNING of the macro definition? In other words, just as if something like `#define JOIN_TOKENS(a, b) ##a##b` were allowed.

An example would be `JOIN_TOKENS(Up, Here)` turning into `UpHere`. Also, I'd like for any values passed as parameters to not be expanded. This almost did it, but it produces an error:

```
#define APPEND_TOKEN(a, b) a##b
#define VAR 0
#define JOIN(a, b) APPEND_TOKEN(##a, ##b)
JOIN(VAR, iable)
```

It was supposed to produce `VARiable`, and it did, but there were accompanying errors:

```
<stdin>:4:1: error: pasting formed '(VAR', an invalid preprocessing token
JOIN(VAR, iable)
^
<stdin>:3:33: note: expanded from macro 'JOIN'
#define JOIN(a, b) APPEND_TOKEN(##a, ##b)
                                ^
<stdin>:4:1: error: pasting formed ',iable', an invalid preprocessing token
<stdin>:3:38: note: expanded from macro 'JOIN'
#define JOIN(a, b) APPEND_TOKEN(##a, ##b)
                                     ^
/



VARiable
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Could you please post an example of your input / expected output to help visualize the result you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That produces a string and that's not what I want.

Comment: @Melab  Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
//encloses the argument Arg in quotation marks
#define STRINGIFY(Arg) STRINGIFY_(Arg)
#define STRINGIFY_(Arg) #Arg

//concatenates the two arguments Arg1 and Arg2 to a new token
#define CAT(Arg1, Arg2) CAT_(Arg1, Arg2)
#define CAT_(Arg1, Arg2) Arg1##Arg2
```

**Test**:

```
#define A MY_
#define B SPECIAL_
#define C TYPE

printf("%s\n", STRINGIFY(CAT(A, CAT(B, C))));
//output: MY_SPECIAL_TYPE

/* or */

#define MY_VAR CAT(A, CAT(B, C))
typedef int MY_VAR;

MY_VAR i = 42;

printf("%d\n", i);
//output: 42
```

Comment: Nope. That produces a string.

Comment: `STRINGIFY` produces a string, not `CAT`. I've added the `STRINGIFY` macro for testing purposes.

Comment: Test with preprocessor output. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742831/9072753

Comment: @heapunderrun Good point.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #define APPEND_TOKEN(a, b) a##b
> #define VAR 0
> #define JOIN(a, b) APPEND_TOKEN(##a, ##b)
> JOIN(VAR, iable)
> ```
>
> It was supposed to produce VARiable

Just use the following code:

```
#define VAR 0
#define JOIN(a, b)   a##b
JOIN(VAR, iable)
```

Produces the following preprocessor output. Tested on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1MEMexxsf):

```
VARiable
```

Comment: That doesn't work when `VAR` is a macro. I mentioned token pasting specifically, so I do not want `a` expanded, just as `b` would not be expanded.

Comment: It does work when VAR is a macro. I do not understand. Edited the answer with an online link. Macro arguments as part of `##` are not rescanned for further replacement.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I was thinking of a set of macros that I thought were similar enough to yours.

Comment: Now what if you wanted `VAR` to expand?

Comment: Then see `CAT` from the other answer....