Uninitialialized variable warning in cmsis_armcc.h
When I run a static analysis (codesonar) tool, I get security issues related to an uninitialized variable in the cmsis_armcc.h file for the following code:

__STATIC_INLINE uint32_t __get_CONTROL(void)
{
  register uint32_t __regControl __ASM("control");
  return(__regControl);
}


The issue is that cmsis_armcc.h is a read-only file in the Keil IDE. Are there any ways I can resolve this issue? I would appreciate any suggestions.compiler : ARM Compiler version 5.06 update 7  Thank you in advance!

maybe this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742822/8339821? it is just a way to start somewhere out. meanwhile, please update tags to reflect your setup. os, compiler, etc.

the answers to above question are many and lenghty. you may try something simple, like cc -E.

Probably get a less generalised answer if you were to be specific about which static analysis tool you are using.  If it is a commercial tool, you could ask the vendor for technical support.

@user14063792468 compiler, and platform are perhaps implicit from "keil" and cmsis_armcc.h if you know what they are.  I added tags to clarify.

tags are not imlicit by definition. some people may browse questions by tags. tags could be used for analysis of SO database(you can a get copy on a quaterly? basis). you get my point, you will have better chances for your question, if u be more specific.

Solutions include:

provide a fake cmsis_armcc.h for static analysis.  It does not need the real one and the include paths for static analysis been not the same as for compilation
instruct the static analysis tool to ignore issues in cmsis_armcc.h

It is normal in static analysis to set all third-party provided files to ignore or provide stubs.  They typically include system level code that would be ill-advised in user code, and often employ platform specific compiler extensions and directives that may not be recognised by the analyser.  I would be surprised if this were the only system file that your analyser would have trouble with, so you need a global solution.
For the first option, copy the real file to a static analysis specific header path, and modify it as necessary.  For the second, that will be specific to your tool, as will the means if providing system include paths for the first.
Given that many of these system files are deeply nested and numerous, I would favour the first option, but there may be syntax and extensions in this code that defeats the analyser.  That can often be dealt with by defining macros for confounding code so that it is replaced by the preprocessor with something benign before analysis.
