# What this macro is expanded to?

Tags: c, macros

I encountered this macros definition in a `C` project.
I face problems expanding the macro. 
Here it is:

```
#define PT_THREAD(name_args) char name_args

#define PROCESS_THREAD(name, ev, data)              \
static PT_THREAD(process_thread_##name(struct pt *process_pt,   \
                   process_event_t ev,  \
                   process_data_t data))
```

Some help? Thank you.

Comment: Just about all compilers are capable of stopping after the preprocessor stage, so you could easily see for yourself what the macro expands to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing expanded C macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985403/seeing-expanded-c-macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `gcc -E` to get the resulting code after the preprocessor.

Running this on `PROCESS_THREAD(foo,bar,baz)` results in:

```
static char process_thread_foo(struct pt *process_pt, process_event_t bar, process_data_t baz)
```