# C: Apply Macros, Don't Compile

Tags: c, compilation, macros

Context: Long time programmer, coming back to C as a baby. Apologies for what are probably obvious to you questions.

Can I apply macros to a C program without compiling it?

My understand of C Macros: They process your source file *before* handing it off to be compiled

> **Me**: Here's my file 
>   **Compiler**: OK, let me apply the macros get something I can compile 
>   **Compiler**: OK, macros applied, lets compile this

Is there a way to view the program file that's actually passed off for compilation?  i.e. a way to apply the macros but **not** compile the program.

For example, I have a small program that uses the `PRIxPTR` macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//needed for the PRI*PTR Macros
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int* pI = &i;

    printf("iP points to address (base 16): %" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pI);         
    printf("iP points to address (base 10): %" PRIdPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pI);                 
}
```

Compiling and running the program

```
$ cc main.c; ./a.out
```

produces the following output

```
iP points to address (base 16): 7fff545f587c
iP points to address (base 10): 140734608922748
```

I would like to see the C source that `PRIxPTR` macro actually produces.

This seems like it would be possible -- is it?  If not, is my understanding of macros incorrect?  Or is there something else that prevents this from happening?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985403/seeing-expanded-c-macros

Comment: At least some IDEs can expand individual macro invocations for you too. I know Eclipse/CDT does this when you hover the pointer over one. Note that the expansion could differ if the IDEs environment and options are different from that of the compiler.

Comment: "Can I apply macros to a C program without compiling it?" - sure. The C **pre**processor can be run before the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gcc, use the `-E` option.  That will generate the preprocessor output to stdout.

```
gcc -E -o src_pp.c src.c
```

Contents of src_pp.c:

```
# 1 "src.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "src.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4

...

# 6 "src.c" 2

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int* pI = &i;

    printf("iP points to address (base 16): %" "l" "x" "\n", (uintptr_t) pI);
    printf("iP points to address (base 10): %" "l" "d" "\n", (uintptr_t) pI);
}
```

Comment: If your compiler doesn't offer this feature, you can try to find the macro definition then do the text substitutions by hand.  That's pretty easy for a few instances.

Comment: Thanks @dbush!  I'd mark this as best but the question already got closed out as a dupe.

Comment: @AlanStorm I think you can still accept once 15 minutes has passed.

Comment: @DaveS: Is there a compiler that doesn't? I don't think I've ever met a C or C++ compiler that didn't.

Comment: So you can @dbush -- thanks again!